# What are the colored blocks in the debugbar output?

Tags: laravel

Looking at output of debugbar, I see some colored blocks:

[image]

Some of them are not clear what for.

I did not find any info in package docs or in `config/debugbar.php`:

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.45.1",
"barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.10",
```

Comment: Not part of debugbar. You may have something else that is conflicting with its CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a CSS issue, that IS debugbar's formatting.

So to the light red markers in each row of the output represents the "time-slice" for that request. See in the image markup below, the total time in the upper right is for the *entire* request, and the time for each output related to the light red section, all circled in yellow:

[image]

---

Then to the 2 debugbar rows with the yellow back ground is reporting duplicate (or repeated) queries, circled in blue, where you can see the same query is called twice from two different places in the `CrudAppImages` file at lines 105 and 116:

[image]

The duplicate query helped show where we had the SAME query being called 100+ times. The issue was that for a given recordset, the query was in a loop fetching the *same* employeeID reference. The resolve was to fetch that ONCE *before* the loop, and pass that to the function in the loop that needed the value. This minor change cut the request time from several seconds down to 100-200 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you, very usefull ! Any remarks what for dark brown block on my printscreen ?

Comment: Dark brown block? Where I have the repeated query? If so, that is the 7 second time-slice, which would be light red like the others, but does not appear the same way against the yellow.